# How do you get the length value from an array greater than 1D in java?

Tags: java, arrays

In java, what would `myArray.length` be referencing in a 2D array? E.g.

```
double[][] myArray = new double[3][5];
```

say you want to run a couple of for-loops over the array without putting the rows and columns in an argument to get hold of their value, is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: Your code should be:  double[][] myArray = new double[3][5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `myArray.length` and `myArray[0].length`.  (This assumes that all of your "sub"-arrays are the same length.)

Answer (score 1):

> In java, what would myArray.length be referencing in a 2D array?

**A 2 dimensional array of double is a 1-dimensional array or 1 dimensional array of double.** `myArray[0]` is a an array of `double` (`double[]`), as is `myArray[1]`

So `myArray.length` is the number of arrays.

> say you want to run a couple of for-loops over the array without putting the rows and columns in an argument to get hold of their value, is there a neat way to do this?

You mean you want to access `myArray[2][3]` without using `3` and `4`? There isn't a way to do this in `Java`

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 5 you can use a different looping construct, "[for each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)", where you avoid using array indices;

```
class Test {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {

    int[][] myArray = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

    for ( int[] outer : myArray ) {
      for ( int inner : outer ) {
        System.out.println( inner );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This prints;

```
$ java Test
1
2
3
4
5
6
```